# Android Studio how to resize emulator without aspect ratio constraint

Tags: android, kotlin, android-emulator, android-jetpack-compose

I'm building a responsive layout with jetpack compose, and I want to test the responsiveness by dragging a corner of the emulator to resize it. However, it preserves the aspect ratio and just scales it, which doesn't help me at all. How can I easily test my responsive layout without having to create a bunch of virtual devices at different sizes?

Comment: Enable split screen mode inside the emulator. It allows you to show 2 apps inside android and resize the screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a decent solution from the experimental developer setting "Enable freeform windows" and this article: https://www.floatingapps.net/freeform

Steps:

1. Turn on developer mode
2. In Settings -> Developer options, turn on these settings
   under "Apps":

   - "Force activities to be resizable"
   - "Enable freeform windows"
3. Reboot the virtual device
4. Open your app
5. Open "Overview" mode
6. Long press on the app icon in the header and select "Freeform". You can now drag the corners of the app.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help: [Resizable Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#resizable-emulator)

It is available in Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1

[image]